# What will be the linq query for below code?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

```
class Program
{
    public static bool Like(string toSearch,string toFind)
    {
        if (toSearch.Contains(toFind))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<string> str = new List<string>();
        List<string> strNew = new List<string>();

        str.Add("abdecacd");
        str.Add("facdgh");
        str.Add("iabcacdjk");
        str.Add("lmn");
        str.Add("opqe");
        str.Add("acbd");
        str.Add("efgh");

        string strToSearch= "acd,abc,abcacd,al";

        string[] desc = strToSearch.Split(',');

        for(int i = 0; i < str.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < desc.Length; j++)
            {
                if(Like(str[i].ToString(),desc[j].ToString()))
                {
                    strNew.Add(str[i].ToString());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        if(strNew != null)
        {
            foreach(string strPrint in strNew)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(strPrint);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How to write a linq query for above code,in this strToSearch variable value will be dynamic,user will enter comma separated values,user may enter as many comma separated values as user wants,I want to write a linq query which will find all the values in List which will contain the value entered by user.
Reason I need linq query,because linq is used in my application. Kindly help me out on this.

Comment: There is a bug here `strNew` is always not null

Comment: And `ToString()` on a string is a no-op

Comment: Don't do `if (pred) return true; else return false;` do `return pred;`

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ expression is:

```
List<string> strNew = str.Where(x => desc.Any(y => x.Contains(y))).ToList();
```

that can even be simplified (simplified for the .NET runtime, not for the programmer) to:

```
List<string> strNew = str.Where(x => desc.Any(x.Contains)).ToList();
```

by removing an intermediate lambda function.

In general there is no "speed" difference between what you wrote and what I wrote. Both expressions are O(m*n), with m = `str.Length` and n = `desc.Length`, so O(x^2). You aren't doing an exact search, so you can't use the usual trick of creating an `HashSet<string>` (or doing `str.Intersect(desc).ToList()` that internally does the same thing).

Comment: I would recommend leaving in the `Like` method as it allows for changing the meaning of the search (e.g. to a Damerau–Levenshtein distance measure).